# Unity UI vanishes when the camera Z exceeds 1000

Tags: unity

We are developing 3D racing game.  After the player's position in Z axis reaches 1000, our Canvas UI is hidden and reset.  If I unparent it from Character controller, it still gets auto reset but not hidden.  If I drag player back to < 1000, it again shows my UI.

Any suggestions why this may be happening?

Comment: Could be a camera issue, check your render distance maybe? or render order, the UI could be getting hidden behing objects around the 1000z position.

Comment: Hey problem was solved after changing Render mode of canvas to ScreenSpace camera from Screen Space - Overlay

Comment: Wait, your UI Canvas is parented to the player? um don't do that; you said "I unparent it from Character controller".

Comment: Also, what does "reset" mean? It's unclear exactly what you mean is happening.

Comment: @jhocking yesI parented it as there are multiple levels so sake of simplicity I did it.THe problem has now solved.See my answer

Comment: Well "solved" in the sense that you are no longer having any problem yourself. However we still have no idea what your problem was, so I'm curious what was going on.

Comment: ohhkz let me rephrase it,

>I am developing racing game
>Player moves foreword on track
>Player has UI (canvas,button,text) as its child
>Canvas's Render Mode was "Screen Space - Overlay"

Clear? Now when player crosses 1000 point in Z axis i.e., new Vector3(0,0,1000)

The UI used to get hide.

After playing with values I come to know that if your canvas's render mode is of "Screen Space - overlay" then after certain limit it gets disable to camera.

Now I have set Canvas's Render Mode to "Screen Space - Camera" and now everything is working properly.I hope I have cleared.Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved after changing Render mode of canvas to Screen Space - camera from Screen Space - Overlay